# Cannot use @Autowired within ConstraintValidator - gives NPE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I have a custom ConstraintValidator to validate a `@TelephoneNumber` annotation as follows:

```
@Component
public class TelephoneNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TelephoneNumber, String> {

    @Autowired
    ValidationHelper validationHelper;

    @Override
    public void initialize(TelephoneNumber telephoneNumber) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String telephoneNumber, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

        if(telephoneNumber == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return validationHelper.isTelephoneNumber(telephoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it autowires a ValidationHelper object, which is marked as `@Component`.

Within my `@Repository` whenever I persist my object via `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(myobject);` I get a NPE as `validationHelper` is null.

My hibernate configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages="uk.co.domain.repositories")
public class HibernateConfig {

    static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
    static final String USERNAME = "user";
    static final String PASSWORD = "pass";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS);
        dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(10);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "uk.co.domain.models" });

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {

        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

I have configured a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="uk.co.domain.validators")
public class ValidatorConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

However this has not resolved the problem. The MVC form validation works absolutely fine, it is just the Hibernate persist operation that fails.

Do I somehow need to tell Hibernate to use this validator? I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The validator instance being used is likely not a Spring-managed bean.  I suspect Hibernate is creating an instance of your validator and using that instance instead of the instance you are creating in Spring.

You either need to get Hibernate to use the Spring managed instance or find a workaround (either instantiate it yourself in the validator).  Consider using a static method - when I validate telephone numbers, the validation method typically doesn't need to make any database calls or anything that requires a lot of dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to autowire within my validator because isTelephoneNumber calls the database so it cannot be static. I also need to autowire other services in other validators. Do you know how I can get hibernate to use the spring-managed instance?

Comment: I don't think you can.  You could use the singleton pattern by initializing your singleton static instance when the `ValidationHelper` is created by Spring.  Then in your validator, call `ValidationHelper.getInstance()` to get the instance.  ... it's kind of ugly but I don't know if there's a way to tell Hibernate to use the Spring-managed instance.